# Is it safe to combine Christmas miniature light sets of different amperage?

Tags: electrical, lighting

I have two sets of 8mm mini lights that specify 120V 5A on the plug and one set of 5mm mini lights that say 120V 2A.

Is it safe to use them together without blowing/frying the 2A set?

Comment: you mean 2 different set of lights that you plug into 2 different outlets?

Comment: Ah, sorry I wasn't clear. I meant that they're plugged into the other, making a long string of lights. They're Christmas lights.

Answer (score 1):

If they are set up with a plug at one end and a socket at the other, should be fine - though I'd certainly suggest plugging the 2A string into the 5A string, rather than the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

Most should be labelled on the packaging, or on the light string itself, with how much current can be plugged into the socket at the far end of the string. As long as you don't exceed that, you should be fine.

(A sequence of a 2A string plugged into a 5A string plugged into a 4A string draws 11A total, and you can't plug that into another string unless (a) its output socket can handle 11A of load, and (b) the wall socket can handle the total load of 11A plus the new string.)

Note that this is one of advantages obtained by switching to LEDs -- they draw much, much less current for the same amount of light, so you can either save power or run more lights. Or both.